# Hash (with Spring) and salt: is this safe?

Tags: java, security, hash, spring-security, passwords

I've a Spring based web app, so I came up using spring-security-3.0.8 (I know, that's not a good reason, lol) and I find out the PasswordEncoder class. In my case I'm using the Md5PasswordEncoder, but I'm not sure if could be the best implementation.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/PasswordEncoder.html

The salt is generated by a SecureRandom.

The whole code is something like this:

```
String salt = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
user.setSalt(salt);
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(), salt));
db.save(user);
```

I don't really need big security but it's just for knowledge's sake. :)

(what about making the salt big as the hash putting the bit to 160?)

Comment: Whenever you have the word `best` in a question, you know it's not constructive. MD5 vulnerabilities [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For improved security you might want to consider [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) or [scrypt](https://github.com/wg/scrypt).
Spring Security 3.1 [supports BCrypt](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html) out of the box.

Further universally valid information can be found in the post [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords).

Comment: Nice link! And thanks for pointing out about Spring Security 3.1. In their site I've downloaded the 3.0.8 because the download page is not updated and it was written that the latest production release is this one!

Comment: It seems they have updated it: [Getting Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/downloads.html): "Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE is the latest production release."

Comment: Good to see it! I've seen that there are two "BCrypt": the one that you pointed out and the BCryptPasswordEncoder. Which one should I use?

Comment: You can use the BCryptPasswordEncoder. The class [implements PasswordEncoder](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java) and uses internally the BCrypt class.